# Windows service create vnc connection

Tags: c#, service, vnc, vnc-server

We have a windows service we want to initiate a vnc connection using winvnc, which connects to a repeater. winvnc is running as a service. This all works well when our UI creates this vnc connection through a process, but we need the windows service to create this connection, because if nobody is logged in on the machine, there will be no UI to start the server, only our service is running at that time.

I was hoping that running the windows service with a user that has administration privileges, log on as service, and act as part of the operating system privileges that the service would act as that user, but that's not the case i see.

So what can be done to make a windows service start a vnc connection?

Comment: If the service creates the VNC connection, do you expect to see anything?

Comment: nope, it should all be done behind the scenes

Comment: See if running your process as a service with the free trial of [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) works. It may give you a hint at the problems you're running in to...